# Does PHP have a function for aggregating time values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, time, aggregate-functions, aggregate

So my query is like this:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',(TIMEDIFF('22:00:00',TIME(end)))) AS time
FROM sworkingtime
WHERE user='magdalena' AND type='work' AND start BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-28' AND (HOUR(`end`) > 22 OR HOUR(`end`) < 4)
AND completed=1
```

My query returns this:

```
02:02:36
03:17:24
03:07:03
02:24:17
03:14:09
```

Is there a way to modify this query to return only SUM of this fields, so one field only?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to or can't do this at MySQL level?

Comment: I'd do it in MySQL entirely and not bother having PHP process it at all

Comment: No reason, it's just more advanced query - I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no special sum function in this case - especially paying attention that you need some time summation, not just simple operation.

To do that, you can apply callback on your array. Very powerful function for that is [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce). For working with date intervals you can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) API, like:

```
$data = [
  ['time'=>'02:02:36'],
  ['time'=>'03:17:24'],
  ['time'=>'03:07:03']
];


$time = array_reduce($data, function($c, $x)
{
   $x = explode(':', $x['time']);
   $c = explode(':', $c);
   return (new DateTime('2000-01-01'))
      ->add(new DateInterval('PT'.(int)$c[0].'H'.(int)$c[1].'M'.(int)$c[2].'S'))
      ->add(new DateInterval('PT'.(int)$x[0].'H'.(int)$x[1].'M'.(int)$x[2].'S'))
      ->format('H:i:s');
}, '00:00:00');
```

-this will result in `"08:27:03"` as string. But if you want to get object, remove `format()` call.

Comment: Nice one @Alma Do "+1"

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array and use this function to sum [Sum time php](http://vasavaa.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/sum-time-with-format-hhmmss-by-using-php/)

Comment: I've tried with this function and it actually doesn't work ok, time sum is never right! Don't know what happens with data but I think there are some problems with time conversions. Anyway I'm doing this one step before in MySQL query, thank you, I've updated question.